# SQL Server installation error: other instance on drive has filepath over 260 characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, ssas

I'm a first-time poster here so apologies for any etiquette lapses, but here is my question...

I am attempting to install SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition Database Engine onto a SAN drive called E: on which a SQL Server Analysis Services instance already resides.

My install failed with this error:

> Updating permission setting for folder
>   'E:\MSAS11.SASDEV01\OLAP\Data\221_Complaints_atkurib_62857693-2ba5-4348-b91e-da6ff92c02d5.0.db\fact_complaint_cedd5416-245b-4409-b490-6e74a0d93b88.0.dim'
>   failed.

When I dig a little deeper (into the Detail.txt file in the Setup Bootstrap/Log folders) I find the reason for the error is:

> Failed to get full path for file
>   'E:\MSAS11.SASDEV01\OLAP\Data\221_Complaints_atkurib_62857693-2ba5-4348-b91e-da6ff92c02d5.0.db\fact_complaint_cedd5416-245b-4409-b490-6e74a0d93b88.0.dim\2.H$fact_complaint_cedd5416-245b-4409-b490-6e74a0d93b88$communication_received_channel_scdkey.ID_TO_POS.0.idf'.
>   **The specified file path exceeds the system-defined maximum length.
>   Paths must be less than 260 characters.**

So the problem appears to be that a file-path within the already-installed SSAS instance folders exceeds a 260-character limit.

Has anyone else ever had this issue and can anyone advise please on how I should proceed..?

Comment: Looks like  you are getting "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception#System_IO_PathTooLongException" exception.
I don't know the exact answer but your given full path is exactly 261 char long. Maybe you can try to install it on "E:\MSAS11.SASDEV01" instead of "E:\MSAS11.SASDEV01\OLAP\Data".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to install the Database Engine only onto the E: drive, if successful my installation 'home' folder would be E:\MSSQL11.SQLDEV01. I agree that the 260+ characters length of the file path is causing the issue, but that file-path belongs to the subfolders of the already-installed SSAS instance on the same drive. I'm not sure why my DB Engine install should care about that separate SSAS instance's folders? And I don't dare make changes to those folders, I fear that would damage that separate SSAS instance.

Comment: Ok, this is unorthodox but as this is happening when the engine is setting the permission entries at the end of the setup you can hack this a bit. Stop the SSAS service before running the setup and rename the parent folder there from "fact_complaint_cedd5416-245b-4409-b490-6e74a0d93b88.0.dim" to xxx and do the same for any other folders that sould break the limit, run the setup and then rename the folder back to it's orginal name.